# Horizontal v-card-title with ellipsis?

Tags: vuetify.js, ellipsis

I'm using Vuetify 2.5 and trying to create horizontal cards as per [the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/), creating a flex-box `div` to float the title and subtitle to the side of the avatar using `d-flex flex-no-wrap`.

I want overly long titles to be trunkated with ellipsis, but with the "horizontal mode" the `div` with the title and the subtitle extends outside the v-card, so the overflow directives don't apply until outside the v-card (or even not at all, since it looks like the title box has grown to accomodate the complete title):

[image: Title overflowing in horizontal mode]

If the `d-flex` is removed the ellipsing works correctly:

[image]

What am I missing about the `v-card` elements?.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/thoni56/pen/RwoJGVj) with the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was referenced at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1086218#c4) and short explanation is here:

> Basically: flex items will refuse to shrink below their minimum intrinsic width, unless you explicitly specify "min-width" or "width" or "max-width" on them.

So you can solve your problem by adding **min-width: 0** to your second flex column.

There's your modified codepen:

```
...
<v-card
  :color="color"
  dark
>
  <div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-no-wrap">
      <v-avatar
        class="ma-3"
        size="125"
        tile
      >
        <v-img :src="src"></v-img>
      </v-avatar>
      <div style="min-width: 0">
        <v-card-title class="headline">
          <div class="truncate">{{ title }}</div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle v-text="artist"></v-card-subtitle>
      </div>
    </div>
</v-card>
...
```

Works at Chrome 88 and Firefox 86.